# Javascript: AES encryption is slow

Tags: javascript, performance, encryption, cryptography, aes

I use [forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) as encryption library for both the gulp script (that performs encryption) and the front-end one (where in-browser decryption happens).

The computer is a i5-6200U w/ 16GB ram and takes about 10 seconds for either symmetric enc. or decryption of a 15MB json file.

My real issue is the decryption time being too long for users (multiple files to load and decrypt take 30s+ on this system).

I'm certainly missing some key element (buffer or... whatever my lack of experience in the domain might miss). Is there something obviously wrong in the following code? Thanks for your attention.

1. Obtaining the data

   ```
   function logic(url){
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.onload = function (event) {
           resolve(xhr.response);
       };

       xhr.onreject = function (err) {
           reject(err);
       }

       xhr.open('GET', url);
       xhr.send();
   });
   }
   ```
2. Decrypting the data

   ```
   load('data/dicom.json').then( bytes => {

       const tIn = new Date().getTime();

       const forge = getForge();
       const pwd = "aStringPassword";
       const iv = getInitVector();
       const salt = getSalt();

       const key = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(pwd, salt, 100, 16);

       var decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC', key);
       decipher.start({iv: iv});
       decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(bytez));
       decipher.finish();
       const clear = decipher.output.getBytes();

       const tOut = new Date().getTime();
       console.log(`decrypted in ${(tOut - tIn) / 1000 }s`); // 10s for 15MB json file

       return clear ;
   });
   ```

Comment: Note that JavaScript is excruciatingly slow when it comes to crypto. Scripting languages without native 32 / 64 bit calculations are good for a lot of things, but fast crypto isn't one of them. If possible you should break out of JS and call a native function.

Comment: Hi @MaartenBodewes, thanks for the info. Ok, good to know. I'm trying to use the "window.crypto.subtle" object. Seems it uses "natives" functions. Do you have an opinion on this utility?

Comment: I haven't got any opinion on that utility, never even used it.

Comment: Thanks. Am now comparing my code's speed vs the following speed test and see how far behind mine could be: http://cryptojs.altervista.org/test/simulate-threading-speed_test.html

Answer (score 4):

Forge up to at least 0.7.1 uses strings for its internal buffer implementation.  (This code pre-dates modern buffer APIs and future Forge versions will use newer APIs.)  This has some consequences when processing large inputs.  As output string buffers get larger during processing the internal JavaScript VM can slow down just doing string processing.  One way to avoid this is to use streaming capabilities of the Forge API such that string buffer manipulations use larger data chunks.  The input can be processed in chunks with `update()` and the output manually built during this process.  Getting the output chunks with `getBytes()` will clear the output buffer and allow the Forge internals to operate more efficiently.  Building your own output with those chunks does not have the same performance impact.

A [test](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/tests/benchmarks/so-44303784.js) was written to check decrypting large buffers with a single `update()` call, many `update()` calls, and with native node APIs.  As the input size increases from 1M to 20M the slowdown of a single `update()` call vs native node APIs goes from ~8x to well over 50x!  But if you use streaming processing the slowdown can be only ~4.6x and not noticeably dependent on input size!  For your 15M input size this equates to ~0.75s vs ~10.31s.  For comparison node is ~0.15s and the WebCrypto API is likely similar.  (Timing from a i7-4790K)

A [test](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/tests/benchmarks/so-44303784.js) was also written to see how the chunk size effected the results.  When processing large inputs it seems ~64k is about optimal using node.js.  This could be different depending on the JavaScript VM and other factors.  The key takeaway is that using streaming with any chunk size (even 1M!) offers improvements to avoid linear buffer slowdowns as input size increases.

An example with improved and more constant performance:

```js
const decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC', key);
decipher.start({iv: iv});
const length = bytes.length;
const chunkSize = 1024 * 64;
let index = 0;
let clear = '';
do {
  clear += decipher.output.getBytes();
  const buf = forge.util.createBuffer(bytes.substr(index, chunkSize));
  decipher.update(buf);
  index += chunkSize;
} while(index < length);
const result = decipher.finish();
assert(result);
clear += decipher.output.getBytes();
```

A secondary issue with the code is that you want to avoid doing CPU intensive code on the main JS thread.  The streaming API will allow you to run each `update()` call via `setImmediate()` (if available) or `setTimeout()`.  This will allow the user to interact with the browser while processing is going on.  If you can also stream the input data fetch then you could start processing while data is coming over the network.  Updating the original code to do this is left as an exercise for the reader.  A smaller chunk size might help UI interactivity in this situation.

Lastly it should be noted that native APIs are likely to always be higher performance than Forge.  The current WebCrypto API does not offer a streaming API but its performance may be high enough that it may not be an issue in this use case.  It's worth trying and seeing what works best.

Also note you should check the `decipher.finish()` return value.

Encryption has the same buffer issues with large inputs and can use the same pattern as the code above.

For those reading this in the future: newer web APIs and Forge improvements may have greatly changed performance results.

Comment: I highly recommend using an asynchronous loop via setImmediate/setTimeout as suggested above. Even when using the native Web Crypto API, you are likely to find that total encryption/decryption time for large files far exceeds 16ms -- which is the most time you'd really want to spend doing anything on the main JS thread during a single turn of the event loop if you want a smooth UI. Unfortunately the Web Crypto API doesn't have a streaming API at this time.

Answer (score 0):

No clue so far, but the code run on the [benchmark page](http://cryptojs.altervista.org/test/simulate-threading-speed_test.html), as shown below, runs way slower:
([source available here](http://cryptojs.altervista.org/secretkey/doc/doc_aes_forge.html))

```
   /*** encrypt */  
   var input = forge.util.createBuffer("plaintext");  
   var cipher = forge.aes.startEncrypting(key, iv);  
   cipher.update(input);  
   var status = cipher.finish();  
   var ciphertext = cipher.output.data;
```

Test run via web page: 35ms, same data in my gulp script: 165ms. No clue why, so far.